The imaginary part of $\frac{ax + iay + b}{cx + icy + d}.$
What is the imaginary part of $$\frac{ax + iay + b}{cx + icy + d}$$? I know that I should multiply by the conjugate of the denominator, but what is the conjugate of the denominator?
Is it $c (x - iy) - d,$ if so, if I multiplied it by $c (x + iy) + d,$ it is not a difference between 2 squares then. So, should I just multiply it term by term?
Could someone clarify this to me please?

Write $cx+icy+d$ in standard form $A+iB$ where $A,B$ are real.

The only imaginary number in the denominator is in $icy$, so that's the only term that changes sign upon conjugation.

Assuming $a,b,c,d$ are real, you have the complex number
$$\frac{A+iB}{C+iD}$$ where $A=ax+b,B=ay,C=cx+d,D=cy$ so your imaginary part is
$$\left(\frac{BC-AD}{C^2+D^2}\right)i$$

Hint:
Write the real part of the number as $K = ax +b$ and $T = cx+d$, respectively, i.e. $$\dfrac {K + iay}{T+icy}$$
The conjugate of $T + icy$ is $T-icy$, so we can multiply numerator and denominator by this:
$$\dfrac {(K+iay)(T-icy)}{T^2 +(cy)^2}$$
Multiply out the numerator, rearrange to isolate real and imaginary parts, and then replace $K$ and $T$.  Then you should be able to see the imaginary part easily.
Note: Once you do all that work, you should get...

 $$\dfrac {y(ad-bc)}{(cx+d)^2 + (cy)^2}$$

